# Adding grahps in HTML based on data from database (PHP)

Tags: javascript, php

I have a table called `flagged_posts` with the following rows:

```
id
thought_id (id of the post being flagged)
user_id (id of the user who is flagging the post)
```

I am trying to implement a graph which (for now) will show how many flagged posts have occured ed for the current date (x-axis will show days, i.e. monday, tuesday etc, y-xis will show number of incidents).

I have seen [charts.js](http://www.chartjs.org/) but, I am unsure whether these charts can be used based on database data. I.e. if monday has 10 flagged incidents, `$mon_flagged = 10`, then use the variable to display data in the graph? or in another way which automatically gets data from db?

Answer (score 0):

https://www.amcharts.com/tutorials/using-php-to-hook-up-charts-to-mysql-data-base/You first need to build your data into an array that will be in a useful format for the chart library.

After you have selected the relevant data, format it into an array something like this:

```
function formatDataForChartsJs($result){
    while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result ) ) {
        if($row['post_is_flagged'])  {    
            $data[$row['date_created']] += 1;
        } 
    }
    return $data
}
```

Then you should end up with an array suitable for use with your javascript charting library. Something like this:

```
$data = [
    2016-03-7 => 10
    2016-03-08 => 15
    ...
]
```

You then need to understand how you will pass the data to front end so that you can use your data with a javascript chart library.

The normal way to do this it to take your php data variable and encode it as a json string.

```
$data = fetchData();
$formattedData = formatDataForChartsJs();
$dataAsJsonString = json_encode($formattedData);
```

Then in your view:

```
<script type=text/javascript>
var graphData = <?php echo $dataAsJsonString ?>
//use your graph data variable with chart.js or other javascript graph library
</script>
```

There is a good tutorial here, but I would advise using json_encode rather than their approach to printing a JSON string.

https://www.amcharts.com/tutorials/using-php-to-hook-up-charts-to-mysql-data-base/